# Why do you multiply by two in this perms and combs question?

Tags: combinatorics

A family of 6 adults and 3 children are randomly sitting around a circular table. What is the number of possible seating arrangements if none of the children sit together?

So far I have $(5!)$ [arrange the adults] $(6)(5)(4)$ [for the three children to go in between the adults]

This gives 43200. It is MC

A) 720

B)2400

C) 14400

D)86400

I am just assuming it is D since my answer is half of that and it seems to be close. Why multiply by 2?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-bad-to-comb-perm-hair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: I think you should calculate $5!\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot4$ one more time.

Comment: Why is that so? Is there some sort of symmetry going on?

Comment: No, I think you pressed the wrong buttons on your calculator.

Comment: Oh... You are right gosh I seem to make more calculator mistakes than silly mistakes

Comment: And for the record, I do agree with you that $5!\cdot 6\cdot5\cdot4$ is the correct answer... Assuming we don't care about which person sits closest to the door or something. "A circular table" is a bit vague in that respect.